# How to install python-dev (for python 2.7) on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, python-2.7

Ubuntu 18.04.
I have a pip (2.7) installation that fails for not finding "Python.h".  I tried this:

```
$ sudo apt install python-dev --fix-missing
```

and got this for output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  python-all
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython-dev libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev python2.7-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython-dev libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev python-dev python2.7-dev
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 29.6 MB/29.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 45.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython2.7 amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1
Ign:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython2.7-dev amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python2.7-dev amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython2.7 amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython2.7-dev amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python2.7-dev amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-dev_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-dev_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Aborting install.
```

What do I need to do to get python-dev installed?

Comment: Did you remember to `sudo apt update` first? it looks like your package catalog refers to the `18.04.1` point release

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo sed -i s,//us.archive,//archive,g  /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or use

```
software-properties-gtk
```

[image]

and choose download from main server.

after that

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install python-dev
```

Both ways change the apt sources to main server.

Comment: Their problem is they likely didn't `apt update` first - and thus are working out of outdated data about the repos.

Comment: Well, that's pretty awesome, a word I'm very careful about using.  Thanks!  (I did run apt update first.)